# when opening accordion, GET url by ID from that article

Tags: php, html

I want to display the article ID in my URL when i press the a href in code beneath

Update, i included the php section and the while loop with the article ID

```
require_once("inc/connection.php");
mysql_select_db("nieuws");
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
$id = $_GET['id'];
$datum = $_POST["datum"];
$titel = $_POST["titel"];
$artikel = $_POST["artikel"];
$checkbox = $_POST["checkbox"];
$titel = mysql_real_escape_string(nl2br(htmlentities($_POST["titel"])));
$artikel = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["artikel"]);
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
$datum = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $datum)));
    if(isset($_POST['add'])){
        if(!empty($_POST['titel']) && !empty($_POST['artikel']) && !empty($_POST['datum'])){
        $query="INSERT INTO nieuws (id,datum,titel,artikel) VALUES ('$id','$datum','$titel','$artikel')";
        $datum = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $datum)));
        str_replace('<br />', "\n", $textarea);
        $result=mysql_query($query);
        $juist1 = true;
        }else{
        $fout1 = true;
        }
    }if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
        foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $del_id){
        $sql="DELETE FROM nieuws WHERE id='$del_id'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        $juist2 = true;
        }
        }
}
```

This is the accordion script that opens on click

```
$('.acc_container').hide(); //Hide/close all containers
$('.acc_trigger').click(function(){
if( $(this).next().is(':hidden') ) { //If immediate next container is closed...
    $('.acc_trigger').removeClass('active').next().slideUp();
    $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown();
}
return false;
});
});
```

This is the FORM part

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
<table style="width:950px; margin-bottom:5px;">
<tr>
<td>Datum:<br />
<input type="text" name="datum" size="20" style="width:100px;" value="<?php echo $datum;   ?>" id="datepicker" placeholder="Kies datum"/><br /></td>
<td>Titel:<br />
<input type="text" name="titel" size="200" style="width:500px;" maxlength="45" value="<? php echo $titel; ?>" placeholder="Max. 50 characters toegelaten"/><br /></td>         </tr>
</table>            
Artikel: <br />
<textarea id="textarea" name="artikel" style="width:500px; height:150px;" value="<?php  echo $artikel; ?>" ></textarea><br />

<input type="submit" name="add" value="Artikel toevoegen" />
</form>
```

This is the while loop where i ADD the row ID

```
$query="SELECT id,datum,titel,artikel FROM nieuws ORDER BY id DESC";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo ("<div id=\"artikeltitel\" align=\"center\">
    <div id=\"containerdatum\">".$row['datum']."</div>
    <div id=\"containertitel\">".$row['titel']."</div>
    <div id=\"container3\" style=\"font-size:12px;\">".$row['id']."
    <input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"checkbox[]\" id=\"checkbox\"   value=\"".$row['id']."\"       />
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class=\"container\" align=\"center\">
    <h2 class=\"acc_trigger\"><a href=".$row['id']."> &#187; </a></h2>
    <div class=\"acc_container\">
    <div class=\"block\">".$row['artikel']."</div>
    <div class=\"fb-comments\" data-href=\"http://www.zpb-polonez.be/user.php\" data-num-    posts=\"10\" data-width=\"678\" style=\"margin-top:2px;\"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    ");
}
```

I don't know what to add more to explain what i'm trying to achive

Comment: Where is your article id? Can't you add it to the `<a>` tag itself?

Comment: hey, no it doesn't work, already tried it.. don't quit understand how to do it then

Answer (score 0):

We lack some information here to be able to help but let's try anyway.

Let's assume that your *article id* is `$row['id']` you could build your link this way:

```
echo '<a href="#' . $row['id'] . '">Link</a>';
```

Comment: Ok let me explain, in the user.php page i add my article with a form, beneath that it's being showed in the while loop, every article has his own unique ID, this article is in a jquery accordion with only the date and title visible, so when i hit the a href part the accordion slides open and the whole article is visible, but when this happends i want that my url changes in ...user.php?ID=... so that every article shows its own iD nr, i need this part to set the facebook comment plugin to work on each article separately.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your page? It's still not clear to me what you are trying to do.

Comment: hmm its a restricted admin page so can't do that.

Comment: You mean to change the URL in the address bar?

Comment: Indeed thats what i need

Comment: You need something like `<a href="#1234">Link</a>` where 1234 is your article Id.

Comment: indeed that's a better way to ask the question :-) and yes the a href has to contain the article id and pass it to the url also when clicked

Comment: $row['id'] doesn't seem to help in the a href

Comment: We still don't know where is your ARTICLE ID. This was asked as the first comment! You need to **describe** your issue correctly!

Comment: well, i added the whole script now, let's hope you understand what i mean and maybe someone can help me now

Comment: anyone an idea? still stuck to show the ID in the url